Store async insert pending .bin files in the external SSD storage instead of boot disk
I have a clickhouse cluster with 3 VMs, each being a shard. I have some distributed engine tables, there are high number of async insert happening on this cluster, the issue I face is that the boot disk of all of these 3 VMs fill up 100%, and upon checking the disk utilization by folder I see that the async insert pending for insertion for other 2 shards are accumulating and taking up all the space.

These folders(shard2_replica1, shard3_replica1) are containing .bin files which Distributed tables stores with data which should be inserted.
shard2_replica1 -- means that data in this folder should be inserted into the shard2.
How can I store these async insert .bin files into my external attached/mounted SSD, instead of these being stored in the boot disk. Basically I want to somehow change storage_policy for these, so I can move these to different SSD or any object storage.

first of all, try to increase background_distributed_schedule_pool_size
/etc/clickhouse-backup/config.d/background_distributed_schedule_pool_size.xml
<clickouse
 <background_distributed_schedule_pool_size>64</background_distributed_schedule_pool_size>
</clickhouse>

second you could define CREATE TABLE ... ENGINE=Distributed() SETTINGS storage_policy='ssd_only' for your distributed table
and define /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/storage_policy_only_attached_ssd.xml
<clickhouse>
<storage_configuration>
    <disks>
        <ssd_disk> <!-- disk name -->
            <path>/path/to/your/ssd/</path>
        </ssd_disk>
    </disks>
    <policies>
        <ssd_only>
            <volumes>
                <ssd_only_volume>
                    <disk>ssd_disk</disk>
                </ssd_only_volume>
        </ssd_only>
    </policies>
</storage_configuration>
</clickhouse>

